# Swift 4: programmatically created button addTarget crashes inside delegated class

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I have created a delegate protocol that creates a UIButton and adds it to the parent's view.

```
protocol ButtonInputFactoryDelegate {
    func buttonAction(in formFactory: SubmitInputFactory)
}
```

In the delegate class i have two methods, one for creating the button, and the second for implementing the delegate's button action.

```
class myButtonClass {

    (...)

    func setupButton() {
        guard let delegate = self.delegate else { return }

        // Button creation and setup

        submitButton.addTarget(self.parentViewController, action: #selector(internalButtonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.parentViewController.view.addSubview(submitButton)
    }

    @objc func internalButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let delegate = self.delegate else { return }

        delegate.buttonAction(in: self)
    }
}
```

In a viewController i have the following

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController, ButtonInputFactoryDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        (...)
        myButtonClass.delegate = self
        myButtonClass.setupButton()
    }

    func buttonAction(in formFactory: SubmitInputFactory) {
        print("Test")
    }
}
```

Then when clicking the button it should get called `internalButtonAction` and execute inside `delegate.buttonAction`

Xcode compiles it without error, but when tapping the button the following error appears

`(...) unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102139200`

Any ideas what could be happening?
Thanks!

Comment: did you try to change ` self.parentViewController` to `self` when add the target

Comment: Does an instance referenced by `delegate` have an implementation of a method of `ButtonInputFactoryDelegate`?

Comment: No, both methods are not in the same class. The “parent” in this case is a “UIViewController”.

Comment: And yes, the delegate has an implementation in the parent viewController

Comment: The target is supposed to tell you where the selector is located. Since your target is the parentViewController, you should write your buttonAction also in that viewController. Or you should change the target to `self`.

Comment: When changing the target to `self` the button stops responding to interactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the button class to add the action to the button:

```
class MyButtonClass {

    var submitButton: UIButton = UIButton()

    (...)

    func setSubmitAction(_ target: Any, action: Selector) {
        self.submitButton.addTarget(target, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

When using it on a ViewController, it has to be this way:

```
myButtonClassInstance().setSubmitAction(self, action: #selector(self.submitButtonAction(_:)))
```

With the action defined in the ViewController like:

```
@objc func submitButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    print("Test")
}
```

The `@objc` is required to pass the function as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

If your `setupButton` and `buttonAction` methods are in the same class, you should change `addTarget(self.parentViewController,` to `addTarget(self,`.

Comment: I have edited for better context. As you can see i have another class